# Comparing two probabilities of winning in two different dice-throwing scenarios

Tags: probability

A throws 6 dice and wins if he scores at least one ace. B throws 12 dice and wins if he  scores at least 2 aces. Who has the greater probability to win?

(Hint: Calculate probabilities to lose)

Comment: I presume an "ace" is a roll of "1"?

Comment: Yes David Mitra

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 3):

For both players $A, B$, we use the hint: For each player, we can compute the probability of losing $P(L)$ to obtain the probability of winning: . $$P(W) = 1 - P(L)$$

I'll get you started on player A's probability of winning:

First, player A will *lose* if the outcome of rolling $6$ dice is that none of the dice comes up $1$. For each die, the probability of not being a $1$ is $\dfrac 56$. Since we have 6 dice, the probability of yielding NO 1's is given by $$P(L) = \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{6}$$

So, for player A, the probability of winning is given by $$P(W) = 1 - \left(\frac 56\right)^6$$

Now, see if you can use the same procedure for computing player B's probability of winning. Then compare!

Comment: Not sure why no feedback, but this needs a TU! +1